# WCF LINQ CSLA Problem

Tags: linq, wcf, csla

I have a solution that uses CSLA for Business Layer and LINQ to SQL on another. We need to use WCF so that we can host our database on remote servers but it seems that the application cannot read the web.config file in WCF project using ContextManager. We tried using ConnectionManager and somehow it worked. Is there a known issue with ContextManager(Of Sample).GetManager(DBName) not reading the configuration in the WCF Project? Or I need to set something on both app.config(UI) and web.config(WCF)? Thanks.

Comment: ContextManager / ConnectionManager are static methods built inside CSLA. ContextManager is what I use to get the datacontext object of my .dbml class.

Comment: your question is very unclear - which application is supposed to read what config?? Web apps/web site read from web.config, any other app reads from it's own app.config. Can you please clarify? Maybe list the names of the apps, and which app should be reading which config from what file.

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionManager and ContextManager both use System.Configuration to read the connection string data from the config file.

Of course a ContextManager connection string is quite different from a "normal" ADO.NET connection string. Is it possible that your connection string is not in the correct format?